# why does RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d break my RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [L]
```

If I access www.myhost.com, I get a 302 Moved Temporarily response redirecting me to www.myhost.com/index.html.

If I comment out one particular line of the .htaccess file like this:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [L]
```

and I access www.myhost.com, I get a 200 OK and I am shown the contents of www.myhost.com/index.html but the URL shows only www.myhost.com

My question: Why does the first version behave the way it does? I would have expected both versions to behave the way the second version behaves.

In particular, I interpret the line `RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d` to mean: if the relative URL is not a directory, apply the rule. So if I call www.myhost.com, SCRIPT_FILENAME should be an empty string, this empty string should qualify neither as a file nor as a directory, and the rule should apply, appending index.html to the root of my host URL...

What am I missing?

EDIT [2014-12-03]
To give you some background, I would like to hide index.html in the URL but show its content. It's for a simple Single Page website with css, js, images and perhaps some php. 
Although I'm interested in hearing how you would solve the problem, the question in this post is not about how to solve it but rather to understand how RewriteCond works with the -d argument.

EDIT [2014-12-06]
After posting a different solution below, let me try to explain what I think was going on here:

1. I'm presuming the empty string of SCRIPT_FILENAME was indeed interpreted as a directory, the root directory. therefore the RewriteRule never kicked in.
2. There was some kind of 302 redirection to /index.html going on. I cannot reproduce it at this moment, so I'm not actually sure what caused it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what now seems like the more logical solution to :

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [L]

ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Instead of trying to reroute all possible paths to index.html, I made a 403.html and a 404.html page and use them as intended.

If I visit `www.myhost.com` I see the content of `www.myhost.com/index.html`. 
If I visit a valid directory like `www.myhost.com/css/` I see the content of my `403.html` file. 
If I visit an invalid path like `www.myhost.com/invalidpath` I see the content of my `404.html` file.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't answer the question you asked. If you wanted default behavior you didn't need to go modifying .htacces.

Answer (score 4):

### mod_rewrite is always tricky

First thing to consider is that there are other defaults and configurations that are likely causing your second issue, of a request to `/css/` being directed to `/index.html`
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

- If `/css/` does not exist, or access is not allowed, it may be matching the `!-d` condition.
- As this is .htaccess, and these are inherited, most likely the first condition (empty request) is being matched.

  - RewriteBase is defined for relative-paths for the current directory.
  - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteBase
  - This would not be an issue in the VirtualHosts directive.
  - You can either add an .htaccess file to `/css/` that over-rides that directive, or adjust your `RewriteRule` to omit RewriteBase, and only use RegEx in your conditions.

Your .htaccess adjusted:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.+$
RewriteRule ^.+$ index.html [L]
```

Now, as long as the`/css/` directory exists, you should be fine.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but have the same effect when going to `www.myhost.com/css/`. I'm getting the content of `www.myhost.com/index.html` but without any styling or images. I think it's because the relative URLs for css and js files are now relative to /css/, but I wasn't successful with using a RewriteCond to skip cases where there was an additional `/` in the REQUEST_URI.

Comment: just a little tweak to the regex, I strongly suggest exploring regex further: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.+/.*$`

Answer (score 1):

I tried this, but still had problems with it (see comment below):

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.+$ index.html [L]
```

My understanding of what this does is the following:

1. `Options -Indexes` : prevent automatically displayingn directory contents in the browser
2. `RewriteEngine On` : Make sure mod_rewrite is active
3. `Rewrite Base /` : Paths used in `RewriteRule` are to be interpreted relative to the root/host (I presume this is also the default behavior)
4. `RewriteRule ^$ index.html [L]` : If the relative path (after the hostname) is an empty string, display index.html.
5. `[L]` means this is the last RewriteRule for this block.
6. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` : If there is no file with the same name/path as the relative path, (AND...)
7. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` : ...If in addition there is no directory with the same name/path as the relative path, the following `RewriteRule` shall apply.
8. `RewriteRule ^.+$ index.html [L]` : If the relative path is NOT an empty string, display index.html.

EDIT [2014-12-06]
The problem with this solution:
If I enter www.myhost.com/asdf/ I'm getting the content of www.myhost.com/index.html but without any styling or images. Upon further analysis I saw that all css, js and image files were being loaded relative to the new base path like /asdf/css/*. Of course it couldn't find any of those resources. So it looks like the second rule applied here. asdf/ is neither an existing directory nor an existing filename, and it's not an empty string either, so I was shown the contents of index.html, but all resources were being loaded relative to /asdf/.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.+$ index.html [L]
```

In this case, it's only when it's not an empty string.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that but I'm pretty sure it wont fix the problem I'm trying to solve. I added some context to my question to clarify what I'm trying to achieve. I could however look explicitly for empty string and only rewrite the url for that case.